# Inner-workings of LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, concurrency

I wonder how the following scenario is handled:

- ScheduledThreadPool producing N elements at a time, each second.
- Eager consumer, that tries to create batches of N objects from queue, instead of processing one by one.

When the producer wakes up, and starts putting elements in the queue (simply transferring objects from a list), lets assume 100 elements at a time, will the consumer wake up immediately, emptying the queue before producer gets to put the 100 elements?

Or can I expect the consuming thread to be dormant for a while longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedBlockingQueue uses single lock (ReentrantLock) for all of its operation.

In your case when you say 100 elements at time it means calling put method 100 times. put method tries to get the lock first before insert. So it is quite possible that Consumer Thread will be given a chance and it can drain the queue.

Also LBQ uses non fair lock so chances of starvation is quite possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Neerav
I made a little test

```
private static void raceforIntegers() {
    BlockingDeque<Integer> q = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

    ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    // Delay producer 1 sec, so consumer always waits at 1st 
    ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                if (q.isEmpty()) {
                    Stream.iterate(0,  i -> ++i)
                            .limit(10)
                            .forEach(q::add);
                } else {
                    ex.shutdown();
                }
            }, 1L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    consumeIntegers(q);
}

private static void consumeIntegers(BlockingDeque<Integer> q) {
    int elememts = 30;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        try {
            int n = q.take();
            int s = q.size();
            sb.append(s + ":::::" + n + "\n");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (elememts-- > 0);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Output

```
Size  Num
1:::::0
8:::::1
7:::::2
6:::::3
5:::::4
4:::::5
3:::::6
2:::::7
1:::::8
0:::::9

5:::::0
8:::::1
7:::::2
6:::::3
5:::::4
4:::::5
3:::::6
2:::::7
1:::::8
0:::::9

3:::::0
7:::::1
7:::::2
6:::::3
5:::::4
4:::::5
3:::::6
2:::::7
1:::::8
0:::::9
9:::::0
```